# Using union or append in pyspark to combine two dataframes of different width

Tags: pyspark

df1.union(df2)

How can this be extended to handle pyspark dataframes with different number of columns?

Comment: You need to use join if you want to combine two dataframes, union is only applicable if columns remain same.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to add those columns with NULL value

```
df.withColumn('missing_column_name',lit(None)).withCol......
```

then perform union.

It also important that the positions each of column should match with the other or else you can go with unionByName.